# In a Jenkins Shared Library, how can I get the branch of the library that was checked out from within the library code?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries

In my Jenkins environment, I have a shared library. One of the things that the shared library does is pull down a Docker image from Amazon ECR using a tag. I would like to be able to use the branch of the shared library as the name of the tag. How can I achieve this?

When using `env.GIT_BRANCH` in the context of the shared library, `env.GIT_BRANCH` is the branch of the repo that is running the job, not the the branch of the shared library.

```
@Library('library') // Defaults to pointing a branch called `production`

runBuild() // Should pull a Docker image with the tag `production`
```

```
@Library('library@experimental')

runBuild() // Pulls down a Docker image with the tag `experimental`
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
@Library('jenkins-pipeline-shared@master') _

import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.LibrariesAction

pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage('1') {
      steps {
        script {
          def my_run = currentBuild.rawBuild

          LibrariesAction l_action = my_run.getAction(LibrariesAction.class)
          for (def library : l_action.getLibraries()) {
            println  "library name: ${library.name}, version: ${library.version}"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The output:

```
library name: jenkins-pipeline-shared, version: master
```

Answer (score -1):

Jenkins doesn't "know" that the pipeline it is running is from a shared pipeline, it uses the library as something that is part of itself. So, the only viable solution I see in your case is to put it as a variable in your shared library. Because all Git related data you will have will relate to the repo running the job.